# Sqlite insert overwriting record

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am trying to create a .NET application that will be storing information in a SQLite file. The issue I am running into is once the SQL command is executed, there is only one record visible, as if the current row is being overwritten.

Table creation:

```
bool pathExist = Directory.Exists(appdataPath + "OnCallDB.sqlite");

if (!pathExist)
{
    SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(appdataPath + "OnCallDB.sqlite");
    SQLiteConnection dbNewConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + appdataPath + "OnCallDB.sqlite;Version=3;");
    dbNewConnection.Open();
    string sqlTableCreation = "CREATE TABLE Calls (Id Integer PRIMARY KEY, name varchar(30), ticket varchar(20), phone varchar(20), day varchar(20), start_time varchar(20), end_time varchar(20), raw_time varchar(20), weighted_time varchar(20), date DATETIME, notes varchar(255))";
    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sqlTableCreation, dbNewConnection);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    dbNewConnection.Close();
}
```

Insert statement:

```
SQLiteCommand insertCommand = new SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO Calls ([name], [ticket], [phone], [day], [start_time], [end_time], [raw_time], [weighted_time], [date], [notes])"+
    "VALUES(@name, @ticket, @phone, @day, @start_time, @end_time, @raw_time, @weighted_time, @date, @notes)",connection);

insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ticket", ticket);
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", phone);
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@day", day);
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start_time", start_time);
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end_time", end_time);
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@raw_time", raw_time);
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@weighted_time", weighted_time);
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@notes", notes);

try
{
    connection.Open();
    insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
}
```

I have ran the command manually to the SQL file and inserts a new row. When I run the above SQLite command, it replaces the row. As far as I can tell. I have looked at the file creation date and time and it appears that the file is just being modified and not replaced.

Comment: I must confess I don't see a problem with the command itself. And I never heard of an Insert behaving as an Update... Do you checked the db values to see if the second insert is effectively replacing the first?

Comment: Sqlite seems to have the ability to replace on insert if the key is violated for example, but only if you use the on conflict clause, I think. Are you getting an exception on trying to include a second recoed with the same key? What about the Id field? I think you are missing the id on the insert an being the default value will violate the key

Comment: You're not running the table creation method more than once... right?  My concern is that there is a chance you're overwriting the table, depending on how your code and design is structured.  Nothing in your code points to a REPLACE Conflict Resolution Algorithm or the ON CONFLICT clause.  I'm not even sure what effect that would have... considering I only know of DROP TABLE, hmm.

Comment: I don't think the table is being created twice, because of the verificqtion of the existencenof the file... But other parts of the code can do this...

Comment: Adding an ID filed manually creates the same result. I'm perplexed. I will do some more testing of this and let you know if I come to fix.

Comment: I figured it out, It wasn't my SQL statement. It was how the file was being created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was not with the SQL statement. The issue was with how the file was being created

Comment: Could you explain with more detail?

Comment: it should be:
bool pathExist = Directory.Exists(appdataPath);
bool fileExist = File.Exists(appdataPath + "OnCallDB.sqlite");
The bool was passing as false because "OnCallDB.sqlite" is a file and not a directory. Dumb mistake. Thanks for the help

Comment: So, in fact you were overwrinting the file. It happens. Bad we didn't saw that.